# False Discovery Rate (FDR)

Tags: false-discovery-rate

I have the following data set in an excel spreadsheet

[image]

This spreadsheet consist of two groups of individuals (Red and Blue); the second column is for the individuals age and the rest of the columns are the mean values for the variables (A,B, C, D), those variables represented a Brownian motion. I want to calculate the false discovery rate (FDR) in this spreadsheet. How can I do that? also in this case what is the best method to do a correction for multiple comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You rank all the estimated p-values from low to high. Then, controlling the FDR at b = 0.05 you do like this (Benjamini & Hochberg - method):

FDR_formula = (rank_number / number_of_test)*b


Rank_p_val     FDR_formula             (Is_p_val < FDR_formula then reject H0)
p_lowest       1/5*0.05                "Not significant" (0.065227 > 0.01)
.              .                        .
.              .                        .
.              .                        .
p_highest      5/5*0.05                "Not significant"
```

Comment: @ eXpander. Thanks! But what is the 0.01 means in the first row in your table? Also the P values in my table are for different variables between two groups?

Comment: @ MJA: 0.01 is the estimated FDR_formula. Yes, you want to correct for the number of tests, in this case the number of variables. So you use the p-values from the 4 different variables (or 5 with Age).